# Problems concerning require() javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, tumblr

I'm trying to run the [JavaScript client for the Tumblr API](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js) but I'm getting a "require not defined" error. I've scoured almost every corner of SO trying to find a way to make it work.

I've managed to use *Browserify* to recognize it but at some point, I'm getting a fs.readFileSync error.

Then I tried *RequireJS* and again it does the require thing but I'm getting a Module name "something" has not been loaded yet for context"

I'm really new to Node.js but if I'm understanding it correctly the require() part isn't something the browser can do right? Can anyone guide me as to what solutions I can take for this? If it helps, I'm not planning to upload this on a server or anything. I'm just trying to run it on my local computer and just planning to run the API locally.

---

Edit:
Here's what I have on my `main.js`

```
var tumblr = require('index.js');

var client = tumblr.createClient({
  consumer_key: '<consumer key>',
  consumer_secret: '<consumer secret>',
  token: '<token>',
  token_secret: '<token secret>'
});

// Show user's blog names
client.userInfo(function (err, data) {
  data.user.blogs.forEach(function (blog) {
    alert('dang');
   });
});
```

When I try requirejs, I do this to reference it `<script data-main="script/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>`

Comment: Which version of node are you using? Plus can you show some snippet of code you are trying to run.

Comment: You have to spare some more details..did you run npm install?

Comment: Sorry! I edited the question to include what I have.

Comment: node.js code does not run in any browser.  Requirejs does not provide node's require() function, it is a built in function in node.js.

Comment: To find out what version of nodejs you are running type "node --version" or "nodejs --version" at the command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you might be confusing server-side JavaScript (Node) and client-side JavaScript (in the browser). The Tumblr API you're trying to use is for Node only; you can't run it in a browser. You have to:

1. Install NodeJS and NPM on your system
2. `npm install tumblr.js`
3. Run the script with `node <script name>`

Start with the Tumblr.js example script, then customize for your own purposes!

Comment: Yeah found another SO answer saying it would be hard to do it client-side. I decided to use the php client instead. Thanks!